# GRASS addon r.tg.grom throwing a Python error

Tags: grass-gis, python-2.7

I'm trying to get [this](https://github.com/edinaj0zs4/topographic_grain_grassgis) addon to run in GRASS to calculate Topographic Grain for my DEM. I've managed to get it installed and functional on GRASS 7.6 on macOS 12.2.1, but after inputting my parameters and clicking Run, it returns this output.

```
(Wed Dec 21 18:36:45 2022)                                                      
r.tg.geom -c elevation=Extract_DEM_H_reduced__GDA1994_AusLamb_@topograin minneighb=3 maxneighb=49 profile=/Users/iair/Documents/topograin.pdf table=/Users/iair/topograin.csv/Users/iair/Documents/topograin.csv
R is installed!
Resolution is kept at: 30 m
Will create map of cell-based TG value, relative relief...
Starting R to calculate Topographic Grain... this may take some time...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File
"/Users/iair/Library/GRASS/7.6/Modules/scripts/r.tg.geom",
line 315, in <module>
    main()
  File
"/Users/iair/Library/GRASS/7.6/Modules/scripts/r.tg.geom",
line 247, in main
    error = subprocess.call(myRSCRIPT, stdout=devnull,
stderr=devnull)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/p
ython2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/p
ython2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.6.app/Contents/Resources/lib/p
ython2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(Wed Dec 21 18:36:45 2022) Command finished (0 sec)
```

Is there anyway I can solve this? I'm very lost here.

Comment: It looks like related to OS. Check [this page](https://splunktool.com/moviepy-oserror-exec-format-error-missing-shebang). It is about another package, but this is the only page I could find with the same error.

Comment: As you probably already noticed, that plugin is not part of the official GRASS addons. It depends on a quite old version of GRASS and R, and outdated R packages. And there has not been any activity on the github repo for some years.

Your best chance for getting help is trying to contact the author thru github, or just pull (or fork?) his R script and step thru it to understand the steps in GRASS and R, and correct whatever is not working.

Answer (score 0):

With GRASS GIS 7.6 you are using a pretty old version.
With GRASS GIS 7.8 and 8.2 I could install the addons without problems.

So, please consider to update your GRASS GIS installation and try the addon again.

PS: Just suggested a manual page beautification at https://github.com/edinaj0zs4/topographic_grain_grassgis/pull/1